# cuda SIMD instruction for per-byte multiplication with unsigned saturation

Tags: c, cuda, multiplication, simd, saturation-arithmetic

CUDA has a nice set of [SIMD instructions for integers](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-math-api/group__CUDA__MATH__INTRINSIC__SIMD.html#group__CUDA__MATH__INTRINSIC__SIMD_1g985e19defa6381f163004ac5dd6e68e8) that allow efficient SIMD computations. Among those, there are some that compute addition and subtraction per byte or per half-word [(like __vadd2 and __vadd4)](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-math-api/group__CUDA__MATH__INTRINSIC__SIMD.html#group__CUDA__MATH__INTRINSIC__SIMD_1g4b780280a83f8e40d68f948a365d73cf), however, I couldn't find a similar function that computes per-byte multiplication for a 32bit register. I would appreciate it if someone can help me find a proper solution.

Comment: What is your exact cuda H/W platform model, etc (e.g. Jetson/nano, GTXxxx)? _Some_ of the newer ones support this, IIRC. Otherwise, I [vaguely] remember an app note on S/W emulation using 32 bit unsigned

Comment: But `vadd` does the hard part already so why do you want to hack 32 bit ints to do what `vadd` already does? Is this for video/image processing or neural networks?

Comment: My HW is RTX 3080 and I have no problem using unsigned, I mentioned vadd as an example, but as I explained in my question I need a similar function for per byte multiplication not addition.

Comment: There is a `vmul` in the _vector_ ISA. AFAICT you're looking at S/W functions that emulate with "device code" per notes on your link

Comment: do you mean assembly instructions? Can you please send me a link so that I see what you mean?

Comment: There is a vector isa page. Yes an asm instruction. But, I found a `vmad` (vector multiply-add) inst. The ISA is the PTX ISA: https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/parallel-thread-execution/index.html The inst purports to support u8. There are probably wrapper funcs somewhere. There _seem_ to be multiple ISAs/inst groups (e.g.) multiprecision, vector, video, neural. nVidia has added h/w blocks over time to handle these vertical markets. May be scattered across docs

Comment: I'll keep looking to see if I find a solution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> however, I couldn't find a similar function that computes per-byte multiplication for a 32bit register.

There isn't one that returns the 4 individual products.

The closest is the `__dp4a()` [intrinsic](https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/mixed-precision-programming-cuda-8/) which returns the sum of the 4 products, in a 32-bit integer.

You could write an 8-bit packed unsigned multiply with saturation like this:

```
$ cat t2048.cu
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdint>

__host__ __device__ uchar4 u8mulsat(const uchar4 &a, const uchar4 &b){

  const unsigned sv = 255;
  uchar4 result;
  unsigned t;
  t = a.x*b.x;
  if (t > sv) t = sv;
  result.x = t;
  t = a.y*b.y;
  if (t > sv) t = sv;
  result.y = t;
  t = a.z*b.z;
  if (t > sv) t = sv;
  result.z = t;
  t = a.w*b.w;
  if (t > sv) t = sv;
  result.w = t;
  return result;
}

__global__ void k(uchar4 a, uchar4 b, uchar4 *c){

  *c = u8mulsat(a, b);
}

int main(){

  uchar4 a,b,c, *d_c;
  cudaMalloc(&d_c, sizeof(uchar4));
  a.x = 1;
  a.y = 2;
  a.z = 4;
  a.w = 8;
  b.x = 64;
  b.y = 64;
  b.z = 64;
  b.w = 1;
  k<<<1,1>>>(a, b, d_c);
  cudaMemcpy(&c, d_c, sizeof(uchar4), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
  printf("c.x = %u\n", (unsigned)c.x);
  printf("c.y = %u\n", (unsigned)c.y);
  printf("c.z = %u\n", (unsigned)c.z);
  printf("c.w = %u\n", (unsigned)c.w);
}
$ nvcc -o t2048 t2048.cu
$ compute-sanitizer ./t2048
========= COMPUTE-SANITIZER
c.x = 64
c.y = 128
c.z = 255
c.w = 8
========= ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors
$ cuobjdump -sass ./t2048

Fatbin elf code:
================
arch = sm_52
code version = [1,7]
producer = <unknown>
host = linux
compile_size = 64bit

        code for sm_52

Fatbin elf code:
================
arch = sm_52
code version = [1,7]
producer = <unknown>
host = linux
compile_size = 64bit

        code for sm_52
                Function : _Z1k6uchar4S_PS_
        .headerflags    @"EF_CUDA_SM52 EF_CUDA_PTX_SM(EF_CUDA_SM52)"
                                                                 /* 0x001c4400e22007f6 */
        /*0008*/                   MOV R1, c[0x0][0x20] ;        /* 0x4c98078000870001 */
        /*0010*/                   LDC.U8 R0, c[0x0][0x140] ;    /* 0xef9000001407ff00 */
        /*0018*/                   LDC.U8 R2, c[0x0][0x144] ;    /* 0xef9000001447ff02 */
                                                                 /* 0x001d4400e6200731 */
        /*0028*/                   LDC.U8 R3, c[0x0][0x141] ;    /* 0xef9000001417ff03 */
        /*0030*/                   LDC.U8 R4, c[0x0][0x145] ;    /* 0xef9000001457ff04 */
        /*0038*/                   LDC.U8 R5, c[0x0][0x142] ;    /* 0xef9000001427ff05 */
                                                                 /* 0x001dfc00ee200751 */
        /*0048*/                   LDC.U8 R6, c[0x0][0x146] ;    /* 0xef9000001467ff06 */
        /*0050*/                   LDC.U8 R7, c[0x0][0x143] ;    /* 0xef9000001437ff07 */
        /*0058*/                   LDC.U8 R8, c[0x0][0x147] ;    /* 0xef9000001477ff08 */
                                                                 /* 0x009fd002fe200fe1 */
        /*0068*/                   XMAD R0, R2, R0, RZ ;         /* 0x5b007f8000070200 */
        /*0070*/                   XMAD R2, R4, R3, RZ ;         /* 0x5b007f8000370402 */
        /*0078*/                   XMAD R3, R6, R5, RZ ;         /* 0x5b007f8000570603 */
                                                                 /* 0x001fc408fe2007f1 */
        /*0088*/                   IMNMX.U32 R0, R0, 0xff, PT ;  /* 0x382003800ff70000 */
        /*0090*/                   XMAD R4, R8, R7, RZ ;         /* 0x5b007f8000770804 */
        /*0098*/                   IMNMX.U32 R2, R2, 0xff, PT ;  /* 0x382003800ff70202 */
                                                                 /* 0x001fc400fe2007e4 */
        /*00a8*/                   IMNMX.U32 R3, R3, 0xff, PT ;  /* 0x382003800ff70303 */
        /*00b0*/                   IMNMX.U32 R4, R4, 0xff, PT ;  /* 0x382003800ff70404 */
        /*00b8*/                   BFI R0, R2, 0x808, R0 ;       /* 0x36f0000080870200 */
                                                                 /* 0x001fd400fe2007f5 */
        /*00c8*/                   MOV R2, c[0x0][0x148] ;       /* 0x4c98078005270002 */
        /*00d0*/                   BFI R5, R3, 0x810, R0 ;       /* 0x36f0000081070305 */
        /*00d8*/                   MOV R3, c[0x0][0x14c] ;       /* 0x4c98078005370003 */
                                                                 /* 0x001ffc00fe2007e2 */
        /*00e8*/                   BFI R4, R4, 0x818, R5 ;       /* 0x36f0028081870404 */
        /*00f0*/                   STG.E [R2], R4 ;              /* 0xeedc200000070204 */
        /*00f8*/                   EXIT ;                        /* 0xe30000000007000f */
                                                                 /* 0x001f8000fc0007ff */
        /*0108*/                   BRA 0x100 ;                   /* 0xe2400fffff07000f */
        /*0110*/                   NOP;                          /* 0x50b0000000070f00 */
        /*0118*/                   NOP;                          /* 0x50b0000000070f00 */
                                                                 /* 0x001f8000fc0007e0 */
        /*0128*/                   NOP;                          /* 0x50b0000000070f00 */
        /*0130*/                   NOP;                          /* 0x50b0000000070f00 */
        /*0138*/                   NOP;                          /* 0x50b0000000070f00 */
                ..........



Fatbin ptx code:
================
arch = sm_52
code version = [7,4]
producer = <unknown>
host = linux
compile_size = 64bit
compressed
$
```

The SASS code appears to be about as I would expect, roughly the same length as the C++ code, ignoring the `LDC` and `STG` instructions.

FWIW, on Tesla V100, CUDA 11.4, the [implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72836654/1695960) by njuffa and mine are pretty close in terms of register usage (njuffa: 16, mine: 17) and performance (njuffa about 1% faster):

```
$ cat t2048.cu
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>

__device__ unsigned int vmulus4 (unsigned int a, unsigned int b)
{
    unsigned int plo, phi, res;
    // compute products
    plo = ((a & 0x000000ff) * (b & 0x000000ff) +
           (a & 0x0000ff00) * (b & 0x0000ff00));
    phi = (__umulhi (a & 0x00ff0000, b & 0x00ff0000) +
           __umulhi (a & 0xff000000, b & 0xff000000));
    // clamp products to 255
    plo |= __vcmpne2 (plo & 0xff00ff00, 0x00000000);
    phi |= __vcmpne2 (phi & 0xff00ff00, 0x00000000);
    // extract least significant eight bits of each product
    res = __byte_perm (plo, phi, 0x6420);
    return res;
}

__host__ __device__ uchar4 u8mulsat(const uchar4 &a, const uchar4 &b){

  const unsigned sv = 255;
  uchar4 result;
  unsigned t;
  t = a.x*b.x;
  if (t > sv) t = sv;
  result.x = t;
  t = a.y*b.y;
  if (t > sv) t = sv;
  result.y = t;
  t = a.z*b.z;
  if (t > sv) t = sv;
  result.z = t;
  t = a.w*b.w;
  if (t > sv) t = sv;
  result.w = t;
  return result;
}

__global__ void k(const uchar4 * __restrict__ a, const uchar4 * __restrict__ b, uchar4 * __restrict__ c, unsigned N){

  unsigned idx = blockIdx.x*blockDim.x+threadIdx.x;
  if (idx < N)
    c[idx] = u8mulsat(a[idx], b[idx]);
}

__global__ void k1(const unsigned * __restrict__ a, const unsigned * __restrict__ b, unsigned * __restrict__ c, unsigned N){

  unsigned idx = blockIdx.x*blockDim.x+threadIdx.x;
  if (idx < N)
    c[idx] = vmulus4(a[idx], b[idx]);
}

int main(){
  unsigned N = 256U*80U*8U*400U;
  uchar4 *d_a,*d_b, *d_c;
  cudaMalloc(&d_c, sizeof(uchar4)*N);
  cudaMalloc(&d_a, sizeof(uchar4)*N);
  cudaMalloc(&d_b, sizeof(uchar4)*N);
  for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    k<<<N/256,256>>>(d_a, d_b, d_c, N);
    k1<<<N/256,256>>>((unsigned *)d_a, (unsigned *)d_b, (unsigned *)d_c, N);}
  cudaDeviceSynchronize();
}
$ nvcc -o t2048 t2048.cu -arch=sm_70 -Xptxas -v
ptxas info    : 0 bytes gmem
ptxas info    : Compiling entry function '_Z2k1PKjS0_Pjj' for 'sm_70'
ptxas info    : Function properties for _Z2k1PKjS0_Pjj
    0 bytes stack frame, 0 bytes spill stores, 0 bytes spill loads
ptxas info    : Used 16 registers, 380 bytes cmem[0]
ptxas info    : Compiling entry function '_Z1kPK6uchar4S1_PS_j' for 'sm_70'
ptxas info    : Function properties for _Z1kPK6uchar4S1_PS_j
    0 bytes stack frame, 0 bytes spill stores, 0 bytes spill loads
ptxas info    : Used 17 registers, 380 bytes cmem[0]
$ nvprof ./t2048
==2696== NVPROF is profiling process 2696, command: ./t2048
==2696== Profiling application: ./t2048
==2696== Profiling result:
            Type  Time(%)      Time     Calls       Avg       Min       Max  Name
 GPU activities:   50.21%  100.24ms       100  1.0024ms  998.26us  1.0084ms  k(uchar4 const *, uchar4 const *, uchar4*, unsigned int)
                   49.79%  99.412ms       100  994.12us  990.33us  1.0015ms  k1(unsigned int const *, unsigned int const *, unsigned int*, unsigned int)
      API calls:   57.39%  279.76ms         3  93.254ms  557.75us  278.64ms  cudaMalloc
                   40.69%  198.31ms         1  198.31ms  198.31ms  198.31ms  cudaDeviceSynchronize
                    1.03%  5.0147ms         4  1.2537ms  589.80us  3.2328ms  cuDeviceTotalMem
                    0.51%  2.4799ms       404  6.1380us     333ns  272.34us  cuDeviceGetAttribute
                    0.30%  1.4715ms       200  7.3570us  6.5220us  68.684us  cudaLaunchKernel
                    0.07%  354.69us         4  88.672us  61.927us  166.60us  cuDeviceGetName
                    0.00%  20.956us         4  5.2390us  3.1200us  7.8000us  cuDeviceGetPCIBusId
                    0.00%  10.445us         8  1.3050us     522ns  4.9100us  cuDeviceGet
                    0.00%  3.7970us         4     949ns     780ns  1.2230us  cuDeviceGetUuid
                    0.00%  3.2030us         3  1.0670us     751ns  1.5050us  cuDeviceGetCount
$
```

Later:
Here is a slightly faster routine (a few percent, on `sm_70`) compared to my previous:

```
__device__ uchar4 u8mulsat(const uchar4 &a, const uchar4 &b){

  uchar4 result;
  const half sv = 255;
  const short svi = 255;
  __half2 ah2, bh2, rh2;
  ah2 = __floats2half2_rn(a.x, a.y);
  bh2 = __floats2half2_rn(b.x, b.y);
  rh2 = __hmul2(ah2, bh2);
  result.x = (rh2.x > sv) ? (svi):((short)rh2.x);
  result.y = (rh2.y > sv) ? (svi):((short)rh2.y);
  ah2 = __floats2half2_rn(a.z, a.w);
  bh2 = __floats2half2_rn(b.z, b.w);
  rh2 = __hmul2(ah2, bh2);
  result.z = (rh2.x > sv) ? (svi):((short)rh2.x);
  result.w = (rh2.y > sv) ? (svi):((short)rh2.y);
  return result;
}
```

It has the disadvantage that it uses CUDA half-precision intrinsics, so it is "less portable" than the previous, and likewise cannot be decorated with `__host__`.

Answer (score 4):

There is no existing intrinsic `__vmulus8()` in CUDA. However, it can be emulated using existing intrinsics. Basically, we can pack the four 16-bit products of four 8-bit quantities using two 32-bit variable to hold them. Then clamp each product to 255 and extract the least-significant byte of each product into the final result with the help of the permute operation. The code generated by CUDA 11 for compute capabilities >= 7.0 looks reasonable. Whether the performance is sufficient will depend on the use case. If this operation occurs in the middle of a processing pipeline computing with packed bytes, that should be the case.

```c++
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

/* byte-wise multiply with unsigned saturation */
__device__ unsigned int vmulus4 (unsigned int a, unsigned int b)
{
    unsigned int plo, phi, res;
    // compute products
    plo = ((a & 0x000000ff) * (b & 0x000000ff) + 
           (a & 0x0000ff00) * (b & 0x0000ff00));
    phi = (__umulhi (a & 0x00ff0000, b & 0x00ff0000) + 
           __umulhi (a & 0xff000000, b & 0xff000000));
    // clamp products to 255
    plo |= __vcmpne2 (plo & 0xff00ff00, 0x00000000);
    phi |= __vcmpne2 (phi & 0xff00ff00, 0x00000000);
    // extract least significant eight bits of each product
    res = __byte_perm (plo, phi, 0x6420);
    return res;
}

__global__ void kernel (unsigned int a, unsigned int b, unsigned int *res)
{
    *res = vmulus4 (a, b);
}

unsigned int vmulus4_ref (unsigned int a, unsigned int b)
{
    unsigned char a0, a1, a2, a3, b0, b1, b2, b3;
    unsigned int p0, p1, p2, p3;
    a0 = (a >>  0) & 0xff;
    a1 = (a >>  8) & 0xff;
    a2 = (a >> 16) & 0xff;
    a3 = (a >> 24) & 0xff;
    b0 = (b >>  0) & 0xff;
    b1 = (b >>  8) & 0xff;
    b2 = (b >> 16) & 0xff;
    b3 = (b >> 24) & 0xff;
    p0 = (unsigned int)a0 * (unsigned int)b0;
    p1 = (unsigned int)a1 * (unsigned int)b1;
    p2 = (unsigned int)a2 * (unsigned int)b2;
    p3 = (unsigned int)a3 * (unsigned int)b3;
    if (p0 > 255) p0 = 255;
    if (p1 > 255) p1 = 255;
    if (p2 > 255) p2 = 255;
    if (p3 > 255) p3 = 255;
    return (p0 << 0) + (p1 << 8) + (p2 << 16) + (p3 << 24);
}

// George Marsaglia's KISS PRNG, period 2**123. Newsgroup sci.math, 21 Jan 1999
// Bug fix: Greg Rose, "KISS: A Bit Too Simple" http://eprint.iacr.org/2011/007
static uint32_t kiss_z=362436069, kiss_w=521288629;
static uint32_t kiss_jsr=123456789, kiss_jcong=380116160;
#define znew (kiss_z=36969*(kiss_z&65535)+(kiss_z>>16))
#define wnew (kiss_w=18000*(kiss_w&65535)+(kiss_w>>16))
#define MWC  ((znew<<16)+wnew )
#define SHR3 (kiss_jsr^=(kiss_jsr<<13),kiss_jsr^=(kiss_jsr>>17), \
              kiss_jsr^=(kiss_jsr<<5))
#define CONG (kiss_jcong=69069*kiss_jcong+1234567)
#define KISS ((MWC^CONG)+SHR3)

int main (void)
{
    unsigned int *resD = 0;
    unsigned int a, b, res, ref;

    cudaMalloc ((void**)&resD, sizeof resD[0]);
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
        a = KISS;
        b = KISS;
        kernel<<<1,1>>>(a, b, resD);
        cudaMemcpy (&res, resD, sizeof res, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
        ref = vmulus4_ref (a, b);
        if (res != ref) {
            printf ("error: a=%08x b=%08x res=%08x ref=%08x\n", a, b, res, ref);
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
    }
    cudaFree (resD);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```